# Sal Cloud could not find aws AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I am using Salt Cloud (aws as a provider) and my profile file is:

```
ec2-profile:
  provider: ec2-config
  image: ami-7e2da54e
  size: Micro Instance
```

I run this for testing:

```
sudo salt-cloud --profile=ec2-private test_minion -l debug
```

I had this error:

```
[DEBUG   ] Using AWS endpoint: ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[DEBUG   ] AWS Request: https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=RunInstances&ImageId=ami-7e2da54e&InstanceType=Micro%20Instance&KeyName=salt_cloud_key&MaxCount=1&MinCount=1&Version=2014-10-01
[INFO    ] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[DEBUG   ] Setting read timeout to None
[DEBUG   ] "GET /?Action=RunInstances&ImageId=ami-7e2da54e&InstanceType=Micro%20Instance&KeyName=salt_cloud_key&MaxCount=1&MinCount=1&Version=2014-10-01 HTTP/1.1" 400 None
[DEBUG   ] AWS Response Status Code: 400
[ERROR   ] AWS Response Status Code and Error: [400 400 Client Error: Bad Request] {'Errors': {'Error': {'Message': "The image id '[ami-7e2da54e]' does not exist", 'Code': 'InvalidAMIID.NotFound'}}, 'RequestID': '6b8f2fb5-b24e-4438-8e45-c6b01dc08519'}
[ERROR   ] Error requesting instance: Errors
Error: There was a profile error: Failed to deploy VM
```

Do you have any ideas ?

**Update:**

I changed the image AMI id.
Now I am having this debug message:

```
InvalidParameterValue
```

Which is (according to AWS documentation):

```
An invalid or out-of-range value was supplied for the input parameter.
```

Comment: It says the AMI doesn't exist. Maybe you're using the wrong region? AMIs live inside of a single region. Also there's no size Micro Instance. Try `t2.micro`

Comment: I tried t2.micro but this is not the problem, I am having the same problem. Actually  I am using https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/ for searching images. This is really weird.

Answer (score 1):

Use AWS CLI to check whether AMI is valid for your region

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-XXXXXXX
```

For salt-cloud profile.conf "size" parameter, the correct AWS naming for it is "Instance Type". You can either check AWS for correct naming. 
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Or you can use salt-cloud command to list the instance type using --list-sizes command

```
salt-cloud --list-sizes <provider_name>
salt-cloud --list-sizes test_minion
```

p/s: Do not take salt-cloud naming for granted, the developers seems alway choose confusing attribute name. It is a good idea to document the naming map to pass to next person is new to saltstack